# Can you buy with a copper after buying Grand Market?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity

If you buy the [Grand Market](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=grand%20market) in your turn, can you then use spare copper to buy something else? Or does doing so forbid you from having bought the Grand Market?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. Technically, you play all treasure cards you want to use *at the beginning of* your buy phase, after which point you cannot play more cards. If you have played any copper, you cannot buy Grand Market, and if you have already bought Grand Market you are into your buy phase already and cannot play any coppers.

There are a few exceptions:

- Cards that give you an extra Buy phase, (e.g., Black Market, Villa). You can play all the Coppers you want in one Buy phase and buy Grand Market in another.
- Cards that remove treasure cards in play during your Buy phase (e.g., Mint, Bonfire, Counterfeit, Mandarin). If you are able to remove Coppers after playing them (trashing them, or something else like Mandarin), they are no longer in play and you can buy a Grand Market.

Of course, additional exceptions may be created...

Comment: Another sort of exception is with Mint.  If you get $11 with two buys, you can buy a Mint, trash the coppers in play, and then buy a Grand Market.

Comment: @RobRenaud This may be obvious, but just to clarify this to people who may misinterpret your comment: all the Treasure cards in play are trashed when you buy the Mint, not just the Coppers... it's just the Coppers are the ones stopping you from buying the Grand Market first.

Comment: @philosophyguy I could be wrong, but I think that rule was originally introduced in Alchemy.

Comment: Another exception is villa..buy a grand market, then villa, then use the coppers you have in hand.

Comment: As long as Mint is Mentioned, Mandarin should be as well.

Comment: Also Bonfire, and Counterfeit.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't kept up at all with expansions for the last few years.

Comment: Your first bullet point has a typo. "...buy Grand Market it the then."