# Abusing my watchtower?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity

In Dominion, can I play my treasure cards first, and watchtower last to gain more cards? I tried this last night, and my friend read the rule that says you only play treasure cards in your buy phase.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your friend is correct.  You may only play treasure cards during your buy phase, at which point you are no longer able to play action cards.

Comment: Does this mean this answer is incorrect: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/5937/2133 ?

Comment: @Pureferret - you can only play treasure cards during your buy phase, but think of it as playing all of them at the start of the buy phase.  You don't play some treasure, then buy some cards, then play more treasure.  Likewise, all actions must be played before the beginning of the buy phase.  Everything in its right order and in its right place :)

Comment: Unless you are playing with Black Market. Black Market lets you play all your tresures in it's "psudo-buy phase". Then you can play more actions, after Black Market resolves.